# boost tuple causing problems with boost bind / boost function?

Tags: c++, linux, boost-asio, boost-function

I figure my issue here is very common, but I just can't quite see what I'm doing wrong here.

I'm doing some boost::asio stuff and attempting to write a templated asynchronous read function.

Here is a function.

```
template <typename Handler>
void AsyncRead(std::vector<boost::uint8_t>& _inMsg, Handler _handler)
{
    #if debug
      std::cout<< "IConnection::AsyncRead" << std::endl;
    #endif
    using namespace protocols;

    typedef boost::tuple<Handler> tHandler;
    typedef boost::function< void(const boost::system::error_code &, std::vector<boost::uint8_t> &, tHandler ) > HeaderReaderFunc;

    //void (AConnection::*f)(const boost::system::error_code&, std::vector<boost::uint8_t>&, boost::tuple<Handler>) = &AConnection::HandleReadHeader<Handler>;


    tHandler t(boost::make_tuple(_handler));
    HeaderReaderFunc x(boost::bind(&AConnection::HandleReadHeader<Handler>, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::ref(_inMsg), t));
    inboundHeader.resize(sizeof(SocketIO::MsgData));
    boost::asio::async_read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(inboundHeader), x);

}
```

Things start going bad in the last statement of this function.

```
boost::asio::async_read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(inboundHeader), x);
```

When I attempt to pass the variable 'x' as a parameter into the async_read function.

The errors are legendary in both length and lack of decipherable meaning.

Just a small example of error output:

```
boost_1_38_0/boost/asio/detail/bind_handler.hpp: In member function ‘void boost::asio::detail::binder2<Handler, Arg1, Arg2>::operator()() [with Handler =  boost::function<void ()(const boost::system::error_code&, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >&, boost::tuples::tuple<boost::function<void ()(const boost::system::error_code&)>, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type>)>, Arg1 = boost::system::error_code, Arg2 = unsigned int]’:
```

If I do not use boost function here, and instead use the commented out line which is a reference to a member function, things seem to work, but I can't put my finger on why that is.

The function signature for the AConnection::HandleReadHeader function template is:

```
template <typename Handler>
void HandleReadHeader(const boost::system::error_code& _e,
                    std::vector<boost::uint8_t> & _inMsg, 
                    boost::tuple<Handler> _handler)
```

Handler is of type:

```
    boost::function<void (const boost::system::error_code & ) >
```

The functions AsyncRead and HandleReadHeader are members of my own class
AConnection (probably not important).

Either I'm missing something regarding the syntax in regard to creating a boost::function
object who's signature includes a boost::tuple, or 
the boost::asio::async_read function's third parameter type is not being matched by my
variable 'x'.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

EDIT:

Here is code that does work, but uses a member function reference instead of a boost::functon.

```
template <typename Handler>
void AsyncRead(std::vector<boost::uint8_t>& _inMsg, Handler _handler)
{
 #if debug
   std::cout<< "Connection::AsyncRead" << std::endl;
 #endif
 using namespace protocols;
 // Issue a read operation to read exactly the number of bytes in a header.
 void (Connection::*f)(
     const boost::system::error_code&,
     std::vector<boost::uint8_t>&, boost::tuple<Handler>)
   = &Connection::HandleReadHeader<Handler>;

 inboundHeader.resize(sizeof(simple::message_header));
 boost::asio::async_read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(inboundHeader),
     boost::bind(f,
     this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::ref(_inMsg),
     boost::make_tuple(_handler)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `x` has this type:

```
boost::function< void(const boost::system::error_code &,
    std::vector<boost::uint8_t> &, boost::tuple<Handler>) >
```

Which is similar to this signature:

```
void handler(const boost::system::error_code &,
    std::vector<boost::uint8_t> &, boost::tuple<Handler>)
```

Yet, the Boost Asio docs say the handler signature should be this:

```
void handler(const boost::system::error_code&,
    std::size_t bytes_transferred)
```

So, your signatures do not match--not even close.  Either you are using some overload I wasn't able to find in the Boost docs, or you need to change the HeaderReaderFunc type to match what async_read expects.

Comment: I wonder why it works when I use the "void (AConnection::*f)(const boost::system::error_code&, std::vector<boost::uint8_t>&, boost::tuple<Handler>) = &AConnection::HandleReadHeader<Handler>; " reference? I'll look harder at what's so special about that versus the use of boost::function.

Comment: I'm not sure...I haven't seen your code where you actually used that pointer to member function with the async_read call.

Comment: I updated the question's code to show the working use case. Perhaps this will help determine what is so different between the two code snippets?

Comment: I think you need to keep distilling the code until you get to just a couple short lines that short a working and non-working case.  There's still too much bulk to chew through.